# iPhone can not play video from my web page (server)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, nanohttpd

I am streaming video using `NanoHTTPD` from android device. Every device can play the video file in web page or using external media player except `iPhone`. Even `Mac` desktop can play the file too. I manually pushed the video file into `iPhone` and it's playable. So there is no issue about video format. When i click on the link iPhone open a video player (inside web page) and nothing happen.

## Response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. After adding the range feature (can seek anywhere using player slider) iPhone can play the video.

```
private Response servePartialFile(String uri, Map<String, String> header,
                                      File file, String mime) {
        Response res;
        try {
            // Calculate etag
            String etag = Integer.toHexString((file.getAbsolutePath()
                    + file.lastModified() + "" + file.length()).hashCode());

            // Support (simple) skipping:
            long startFrom = 0;
            long endAt = -1;
            String range = header.get("range");
            if (range != null) {
                if (range.startsWith("bytes=")) {
                    range = range.substring("bytes=".length());
                    int minus = range.indexOf('-');
                    try {
                        if (minus > 0) {
                            startFrom = Long.parseLong(range
                                    .substring(0, minus));
                            endAt = Long.parseLong(range.substring(minus + 1));
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }

            // Change return code and add Content-Range header when skipping is
            // requested
            long fileLen = file.length();
            if (range != null && startFrom >= 0) {
                if (startFrom >= fileLen) {
                    res = createResponse(Response.Status.RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE,
                            NanoHTTPD.MIME_PLAINTEXT, "");
                    res.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-0/" + fileLen);
                    res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
                } else {
                    if (endAt < 0) {
                        endAt = fileLen - 1;
                    }
                    long newLen = endAt - startFrom + 1;
                    if (newLen < 0) {
                        newLen = 0;
                    }

                    final long dataLen = newLen;
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file) {
                        @Override
                        public int available() throws IOException {
                            return (int) dataLen;
                        }
                    };
                    fis.skip(startFrom);

                    res = createResponse(Response.Status.PARTIAL_CONTENT, mime,
                            fis);
                    res.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + dataLen);
                    res.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + startFrom + "-"
                            + endAt + "/" + fileLen);
                    res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
                }
            } else {
                if (etag.equals(header.get("if-none-match")))
                    res = createResponse(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED, mime, "");
                else {
                    res = createResponse(Response.Status.OK, mime,
                            new FileInputStream(file));
                    res.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + fileLen);
                    res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            res = createResponse(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN,
                    NanoHTTPD.MIME_PLAINTEXT, "FORBIDDEN: Reading file failed.");
        }

        return res;
    }
```